# Get all Iframe tag inside a textarea having src as http using jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a textarea with id 'description', User can place as many iframe  inside it, I want when user clicks on submit button system scan all Iframes and if there is any iframe which src is http system show an alert message that Iframe src from http site are not allowed. If Iframe src is https then its ok.

I am trying below code

```
jQuery("form[name=myform]").bind('submit',function(){
    var content = jQuery('#description').val();
    alert($(content).find('iframe').attr('src','http://'));
});
```

But its not working.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping you content in a div and then perform find

```
    jQuery("form[name=myform]").on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var content = jQuery('#description').val();
        alert($('<div>'+content+'</div>').find('iframe[src^="http:"]'));
        if ($('<div>'+content+'</div>').find('iframe[src^="http:"]').length > 0) {
          alert('Iframes over http aren't allowed ');     
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks above is working, please put a ' after iframe[src^="http:"]

Comment: alert($('<div>'+content+'</div>').find('iframe[src^="http:"]));  should be           alert($('<div>'+content+'</div>').find('iframe[src^="http:"]'));